# Set starting directory for foobar2000 via wine

Tags: wine, directory, foobar2000

I used to run Ubuntu 16.10. I had configured foobar2000 the same way via wine that I have now.
I often attach covers to new additions of my music library via foobar:
Back then foobar used to remember the previous directory from which a picture had been selected (so almost always `/home/user/Downloads` in my case). If some sub-directory no longer existed (because I had deleted it) foobar fell back to the `/`, *My computer*, *My Documents*, *Trash* menu next time, so I had to click *My Computer → /Z: → home → user → Downloads*.

However on Ubuntu 18.04 I have to click through all of that each time that I export or attach a cover - no matter what.

Can I somehow get back to the old behavior?
Or could I add Downloads to favorites (I can see an empty Favorites Folder in the left corner of foobar's file browser), so I only have to click one thing instead of five each time?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: How are you starting Foobar2000 currently? From a launcher? If so, could you please run `grep -lie '^Exec=.*\<foobar2000.exe\>' -R ~/.local/share/applications --include='*.desktop'` and add the content of all matching files to your question? Thanks.

Comment: I entered what you said, but it didn't return anything. It seemed to just execute whatever the command does and give a new prompt where I can enter my next command. Yes, I am starting via the wine launcher.

Comment: What's "the wine launcher"? I'm not aware of any canonical way to start applications with Wine. Could you please [edit] your question to describe how *exactly* you start Foobar2000? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up winecfg > Windows Version: and switch to an earlier version > click apply.

Certainly XP would restore prior behavior,anything newer will likely have the current behavior you don't like.